# MySQL Stored Procedure Returning Wrong Result

Tags: mysql

I cannot work out what I am doing wrong. My tables has 1262717 rows.

I have this SQL:

```
SELECT count(hud_case_number) FROM suitecrm.ht_homes where hud_case_number = "abc"
```

Which correctly replies with 0

When I convert it to a stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `hud_does_property_exist`(IN hud_case_number varchar(20))
BEGIN
SELECT count(hud_case_number) FROM suitecrm.ht_homes where hud_case_number = hud_case_number;
END
```

and call it like this:

```
Call hud_does_property_exist('abc')
```

It returns the answer 1262717

I just cannot see what I am doing wrong. I suspect it's something to do with the hud_case_number parameter?

Comment: I'm guessing that `1262717` is the total number of rows, and it will be happening because it's checking to see where the field `hud_case_number` equals itself.  Change the name of the `IN` parameter and it should work.

Comment: Best not to use the same name for parameters and field.

Comment: OMG - thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Try This :-

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `hud_does_property_exist`(IN 
in_hud_case_number varchar(20))
BEGIN
  SELECT count(hud_case_number) FROM suitecrm.ht_homes where hud_case_number = 
  in_hud_case_number;
END
```